# Swift : Begginer question - print even numbers

Tags: while-loop, numbers

so I just started to learn to code in siwft and I want this code to print me even numbers, while the number is <= 20, but it doesnt work. what is wrong with it ? thx

```
var number = 1
repeat {
    print(number)
    number += 1
} while number <= 20 && number % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(Array(0...20).filter{$0%2==0})
```

Basically, Using range operator, u create range of numbers and convert into an array and filter the elements which are multiples of 2.